# Timeout.bas equivalent for Visual Basic using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Are there any `Timeout.bas` equivalents for Visual Basic using Visual Studio 2010

I have this file called timeout.bas that I could add to projects in earlier versions of visual basic that basically let me use the code:

```
Timeout .5
```

I'm trying to get the same kind of file for Visual Studio 2010

So I can write code such as:

```
Label1.text = "hello"
Timeout 1 
label1.text = "good day!"
```

It's basically just a pause or delay.... Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably don't want to hear this, but doing things like that in a framework-type environment doesn't work very well (although I think this specifically might).  The way you used to solve time-based problems in VB while being ignorant of threads of execution likely won't hold up in VB.NET.  Typically this is done with callbacks and a timer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea that might work... try re-writing timeout() in VB.NET:

NOTE:  Below is untested pseudocode, specifically the time stuff.  Maybe write a unit-test or so to see if this will work.

```
Sub timeout(duration)
     DateTime endtime = DateTime.Now().AddMilliseconds(duration)
     Do While DateTime.Now() < endtime
         Application.DoEvents()
     Loop 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here how to do it with a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(VS.80).aspx). You have to split your original routine into two parts.

```
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Form1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
    TextBox1.Text = "hi"

    Dim tmr As New Timer
    tmr.Enabled = True
    tmr.Interval = 3000 ' milliseconds '
    AddHandler tmr.Tick, AddressOf ContinueWork
  End Sub

  Sub ContinueWork()
    TextBox1.Text = "hi2"
  End Sub

End Class
```

Be aware that the user can continue to click around your application while the timer interval is running.

I am not sure *why* you would want to do this, it seems odd behaviour for an application, but I'm sure you have your own good reasons!